# How can i export multiple tables from a MS Access DB to Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, export

I can export Access tables one by one using the Oracle ODBC in access. How can i do all tables in the database at once?

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) (a free program from Oracle) has a tool that will export MS access databases for loading into Oracle. Once you have it installed it's Tools -> Migration -> Microsoft Access Exporter. One caveat is it needs Access installed.

Comment: what is difference between Microsoft Access Exporter and Migration option that below answer has been suggested ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Developer 'Migration Wizard' too. Tools -> Migration -> Migration

Comment: what is difference between Microsoft Access Exporter and Migration option that below answer has been suggested ?